# How to troubleshoot private method 'through_reflection' called for ActiveRecord::Associations?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have run in to this error a couple times in rails 5.2 (didn't notice it or catch it prior to that).  I wasn't able to find any good info on SO or rails docs.  I finally figured out what it is...so, I thought I would post a Q/A here for others to find.

```
private method `through_reflection' called for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyThroughAssociation:0x00007ff1d4511878>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very descriptive error...what it means (probably) is that you are calling a has_many through before the through is defined. You need to reorder your associations.

Or, your has_many through association is not formatted correctly.  Again, the error isn't super helpful in figure out what exactly went wrong.